# extract text between 2 span tag via python selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath, text

```
<li class="page-item active">
  <span class="page-link">
    "12"
    <span class="hjhs">(current)</span>
  </span>  
</li>
```

from the above code I need to get extract "12".
I tried

```
xpath = "//li[@class='page-item active']/span"
find_element_by_xpath(xpath).text
```

but i am getting (current) not the "12"

would you please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
xpath = "//span[@class='page-link']"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//li[@class='page-item active']/span/text()
```

Here you go just use /text()

```
print(find_element_by_xpath(xpath))
```